# Deserializing json file into an object C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm practicing c#, and i was trying to read this nested JSON file into a nested object. I think i'm missing something. Here's what i have so far.

#### Quiz.json:

```
    {
        "quiz": {
            "sport": {
                "q1": {
                    "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                    "options": [
                        "New York Bulls",
                        "Los Angeles Kings",
                        "Golden State Warriros",
                        "Huston Rocket"
                    ],
                    "answer": "Huston Rocket"
                }
            },
            "maths": {
                "q1": {
                    "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                    "options": [
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12",
                        "13"
                    ],
                    "answer": "12"
                },
                "q2": {
                    "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                    "options": [
                        "1",
                        "2",
                        "3",
                        "4"
                    ],
                    "answer": "4"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Quiz.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace Practic
    {
        class Quiz
        {
            public Sport sport { get; set; }
            public Maths maths { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

#### Sport.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace Practic
    {
        class Sport
        {
            public Q1 q1 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

#### Maths.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace Practic
    {
        class Maths
        {
            public Q1  q1 { get; set; }
            public Q2 q2 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

#### Q2.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace Practic
    {
        class Q2
        {
            public string question { get; set; }
            public IList<string> options { get; set; }
            public string answer { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

#### Q1.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    
    namespace Practic
    {
        class Q1
        {
            public string question { get; set; }
            public IList<string> options { get; set; }
            public string answer { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

#### Program.cs:

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    
namespace Practic
{
    class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Quiz Quiz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quiz>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Anthony Salvatore\source\repos\Practic\Practic\Quiz.json"));

            // deserialize JSON directly from a file
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\Anthony Salvatore\source\repos\Practic\Practic\Quiz.json"))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                Quiz Quiz2 = (Quiz)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(Quiz));
                Console.WriteLine(Quiz2.maths);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally i want to run the program.cs, and i'm expecting the Quiz object to be populated, and when i print `Console.WriteLine(Quiz2.maths);` i am expecting an output, but all i get is a blank line. can someone help me with what i'm missing? am i populating the object wrong? or referencing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You don't need `Q2` class it's same to `Q1` class, use just `Q1`.
2 - You should add a `RootObject` that contains `Quiz` property for the json root, and use this class during deserialization instead of `Quiz` class.

```
class RootObject
{
    public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
}
```

3 - You can't use `Console.WriteLine` for reference type like `Maths`, but you can display each property of `Maths` or `Sport`.

**Result**:

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Anthony Salvatore\source\repos\Practic\Practic\Quiz.json"));
Quiz quiz = root?.Quiz;

// deserialize JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\Anthony Salvatore\source\repos\Practic\Practic\Quiz.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    RootObject root2 = (RootObject)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(RootObject));

    Console.WriteLine($"Maths q1: {root2.Quiz.maths.q1.answer}, {root2.Quiz.maths.q1.question}," +
        $" {string.Join(",", root2.Quiz.maths.q1.options)}");

    Console.WriteLine($"Maths q2: {root2.Quiz.maths.q2.answer}, {root2.Quiz.maths.q2.question}," +
        $" {string.Join(",", root2.Quiz.maths.q2.options)}");

    Console.WriteLine($"sport: {root2.Quiz.sport.q1.answer}, {root2.Quiz.sport.q1.question}," +
        $" {string.Join(",", root2.Quiz.sport.q1.options)}");
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: This works! what is this doing? Quiz quiz = root?.Quiz;

Comment: Access to the property `Quiz`. and ? : it's like if root is null return null. For more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Answer (score 0):

instead of use "q1" and "q2", please use "QuestionNumber" property like "QuestionNumber:1" and assign question number. it will help you to store multiple questions and easy to serialize data.

You can also use dynamic Datatype to read unpredictable JSON format.